# Can we get time for each revision in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I have used "/{index}/{id}?revs_info={_revinfo}" to get all versions for given id, i am getting status and revision info as response but is there any possibility to get time for each revision id.

Comment: Nope, but when you create your docs you can put specific fields like createdOn/updatedOn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered on the CouchDB mailing list, see [this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/couchdb/user/09bbdqhqcm/getting-revision-date).

Ultimately, the answer is no. CouchDB does **not** store timestamps along with any revisions.